# Is having more android SDK in Android Studio always better?

Tags: android

Recently, I have been wondering if having all/most of the android app SDK really helps in the android development process. Can anyone please tell me what are the benefits of having most/all of the android sdk(all api's) in android studio? If having only one of the android sdk of the most recent api(recent api is 24) is enough then it may help to free up a lot of spaces.

Answer (score 1):

If you have more SDK then you can create multiple emulator with different API level to test